# How to use cell reference in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use a formula in current cell with reference to the cell above it in R. For example:

```
data$srno = data$srno[offset(-1,0)] + 1
```

Is there a way we can code this in R ?

Comment: Try `data$srno = c(1, data$srno[1:(dim(data)[1]-1)]+1)`

Comment: @sharad did any of the suggestions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

What may be more convenient for you is to use a lag or shift function from different packages.

Here are some different ways of tackling the challenge:

```
myvector<-1:26

# base version
1+c(0,myvector[1:length(myvector)-1])

# returns an NA for 1st row
1+Hmisc::Lag(myvector)

1L + data.table::shift(myvector, fill=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the top cell has no cell above it. One approach is to use NA for that cell:

```
data$srno <- c(NA,data$srno[-length(data$srno)]+1);
```

Another approach is to consider the bottom cell to "wrap around", so that it can be used in the formula for calculating the new value for the top cell. Whether this makes sense depends on your data/formula, but here's how it could be done:

```
data$srno <- data$srno[c(length(data$srno),1:(length(data$srno)-1))]+1;
```